# Deserializing packet over network, send System.Type or a better way?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, serialization

In my code I have a packet class that I send over the network, inside this packet struct I have a Type variable which is inside the packet similar to this:

```
[Serializable]
struct Packet 
{
    Type packetType;
}
```

And then on the client/server I can deserialize by doing the following:

```
if(packet.packetType == typeof(ChatPacket))
{
    ChatPacket packet = packet as ChatPacket;
}
```

This works fine, however I can't help but feel `System.Type` must have significant overhead. Can someone shed some light on this?

And if it is wasteful then what is a better approach I could take to deal with multiple packets (ideally something that can be extended outside of the class library `Packet` is already contained in.

Comment: "_I can't help but feel `System.Type` must have significant overhead._" Why? What evidence do you have got that opinion?

Comment: In the VS debugger it shows a lot of members, but I'm not sure if that's just visual studio showing the reflection data or not. I haven't been able to find any info online and was having issues seeing exactly how many bytes I was sending over the sockets.

Comment: I've done some further checking and it seems that System.Type appears to have approximately 220 bytes of overhead in my implementation (using a binaryformatter)

Comment: "I can deserialize" - code shown is not deserialization but just cast... Obviously you already have object of correct type due to whatever deserialization you pick doing things right for you - so why do you need extra field that duplicates this info?